# JQuery - Highlight an element using ajax based on values in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Ok, so I've looked through documentation and Googled this, yet surprisingly I can't find a solution and nobody seems to be having the same trouble I am. I am fairly new to JQuery AJAX, and I am putting together a sort of booking calendar from scratch and I am looking for a way to highlight elements or "dates" in the calendar GUI based on whether that "date" has bookings in the database. Here's the block of JQuery I'm tinkering with, but I feel like I'm way off for some reason.

```
$(".box").load(function() {
    date_time = $(this).attr('id');
    month = $(this).attr('month');
    year = $(this).attr('year');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/book.me/check.php', 
        data: "date=" + date_time + "&month=" + month + "&year=" + year, 
        success: function(msg) { 
                $(this).css("background-color", "#cccccc");
        }
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: As a side note, it would make your code more flexible and easier to maintain if instead of manually setting the background color you put the styling in your CSS and use  [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) to add it: `.addClass("highlight")`. That way you can easily find all highlighted cells. For instance, if you wanted to remove the highlighting on all the highlighted cells you could do something like `$(".box.highlight").removeClass("highlight");`

Answer (score 1):

You are pointing to a different object in success. Use `var that = $(this);` and `that.css("background-color", "#cccccc");` if you are planning to highlight `.box` like below.

```
$(".box").load(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    date_time = $(this).attr('id');
    month = $(this).attr('month');
    year = $(this).attr('year');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/book.me/check.php', 
        data: "date=" + date_time + "&month=" + month + "&year=" + year, 
        success: function(msg) { 
                that.css("background-color", "#cccccc");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok, so it didn't "seem" to work. I changed my code to yours and added an error option to the ajax for testing, but it returns nothing, and I'm still not getting the intended result.

Comment: Is success function called?

Comment: No, It doesn't seem to be doing anything on the load event.

Comment: debug it. Sounds like you have other problems